# Communication b/w two WiFi modules using Arduino Ide

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmega16

Firstly, I'll just give you a brief introduction about our project... its "***Speech controlled Home Automation System***" where we are controlling the Home appliances by the voice or speech commands. We're successfully done with the voice recognition module. But our problem is with achieving the communication between the transmitter {where the user gives the voice command} and receiver {where the home appliances are present} through WiFi i.e. *we have got 2 ESP8266* 12E *modules interfaced with Arduino* both at the transmitter and receiver side and these two WiFi modules need to be communicated(To interchange some data sent by Arduinos).So please let us know which Arduino code need to be used at  transmitter side wifi module and at Receiver side wifi module and also about the header files or additional softwares(if any)to be used.

Comment: Don't spam tags! Arduino is not C and how is that related to the other tags?

Comment: do you want to send voice (audio) data or just little command packets? if both ESPs are on the same wifi, you can use the client lib on one and the httpserver lib on the other, or something fancier like websockets

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this by starting one of wifi modules in Access Point Mode and the other one has to be set to Station Mode in order to connect to the first one.
In case you want to add a router, just set both ESP8266 modules to Station Mode and connect them to the router.
And then transfer any data you want through AT commands of ESP8266.
Here is the refrence to them.

https://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/26/esp8266-at-command-reference/

If you are newbie to Esp8266 and Arduino , this will help you.

http://www.teomaragakis.com/hardware/electronics/how-to-connect-an-esp8266-to-an-arduino-uno/

Good Luck !

Answer (score -1):

I worked on a similar system a year ago. I was developing a remote controlled toy. My main difference was I used the ESP8266 without an Arduino attached. 
One ESP worked as a a WiFi hotspot and the other connected to it, sending messages through UDP.

For some reason, I could not get the two ESP modules to connect (I think it was a problem with the board I had), but I sent messages from my computer, and it worked out fine. I will not burden you with all of the code, but [here](https://github.com/Marsfan/Toy-Sub-Project) is the GitHub link.

All that needs to happen is they will be on the same WiFi network, and then you can use the ESP8266 WiFi library to send messages between the two. Like I said above, I used UDP, which is good for high speed, with no error checking. But there is also TCP (higher up, has error checking code), or you can use the server/client part of the library to set up a full web server and read/write data to it. Without knowing what type of data, I cannot comment on what would be the best method.

As for headers, you will need `WiFi.h`, and if you are using UDP you will need `WiFiUdp.h`

You should not need any external software besides the Arduino IDE. 
I taught myself from scratch for this product, using two main resources: the Arduino library reference, and the docs on the ESP8266 Arduino GitHub page